# jQuery .toggle() making button disappear

Tags: jquery, html, css, frontend

I have a filter nav bar that when each button is clicked, it only shows those projects with the corresponding category.  When the all button is clicked, it displays all of them.  Furthermore, when button is clicked, it adds the selected class, which changes the background color.

The goal:  To when the button is clicked a second time (if it is already selected), to have everything display again and for the button to be deselected.

The problem:  I believe having the `.toggle(fn1{}, fn2{})` method would the the correct way to go, where fn1 would show the selected class on button and only display the corresponding projects, and fn2 would return everything back to original display.  However, when using the .toggle() method, it makes the whole button disappear (currently being applied to the 'web design' button).

So heres the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ecndtck/).

Comment: that particular version of [.toggle(fn, fn)](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed) was removed in jQuery 1.9

Comment: anyway i can achieve the same affect in 2.1.  Would it be easier to leave the code as is and use a jQuery migration?  If so, would it cause any interferences?  Thanks, somewhat new to using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
var $all = $("#projects").find("li.wrap");

$('#all-btn').click(function () {
    $("#nav-filter li").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $all.fadeIn(1000);
});

//toggle is making button dissappear
$('#nav-filter li[data-type]').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $clis = $all.filter('.' + this.dataset.type)
    $this.toggleClass("selected");
    $('#nav-filter li').not(this).removeClass('selected');
    if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
        $all.not($clis).fadeOut(1000);
        $clis.fadeIn(1000);
    } else {
        $all.fadeIn(1000);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/b9zvoafj/)